# Excel Smart Tags

Tags: excel, smart-tags

Can someone point me to a good tutorial for implementing Excel Smart Tags in Visual Studio? Either with C# or VB.NET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need VSTO for it to be less of a pain. More [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/pstubbs/archive/2005/02/08/369245.aspx)